# Windows 8: Disabling Back button to a frame for a deleted item

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question or going about this the wrong way, but I'm developing a Windows 8 App using the GridApp project template.

In the itemdetail template I have the ability to delete the item you are looking at. After deleting it I navigate back to the main entry page of the app.

however, the back button is there and if I click it, it tries to go back to that frame for the object that was deleted.

how do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

In your delete function you can call `GoBack()` so that right after deletion the page automatically navigates to the main page.

Also back button should have following code

`IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}"`

which enable's and disable's the back button depending upon if there is a page to go back to.

As you said `GoHome()` is the best solution to this problem.

[Little more detail on page navigation in Windows 8/RT](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/winrt-xaml-navigating-page)

Comment: well I do have that code for IsEnabled but it still shows up as enabled. I think I might be doing it wrong. how do I tell the app that it can't go back? I can't call GoBack as you said, because the previous frame may also be tied to the deleted item, so I need to have it go to the root frame and stop there.

Comment: you can always just go back to the main frame by `Frame.Navigate(typeof (NameOfMainFrame));`.

Comment: Using `Frame.Navigate(typeof(NameOfMainFrame));` will just make the problem worse.  If you want to go back to your home screen, I'd use `GoHome()`, which is actually implemented as `while (this.Frame.CanGoBack) this.Frame.GoBack();`.  It won't clear your navigation stack, but will rewind it all the way to the start.  Your back button should then be disabled since there is nowhere further to go in the back stack.

Comment: GoHome() worked PERFECTLY! thanks! can you add this as an answer so I can mark it as such? thanks for your input too Maynak!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the built in Commanding mechanism associated with a button:

Xaml:

viewModel:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    _goBackCommand=new DelegateCommand(GoBackMethod,CanGoBackMethod);
}
public ICommand GoBackCommand
{
    get{return _goBackCommand;}
} 

private void GoBackMethod()
{
    Frame.Navigate(blah);
}

private bool CanGoBackMethod()
{
    return _isDeleted;
}

public void Delete()
{
    _isDeleted=false;
    //this forces the command to re-evaluate whether it can execute
    _goBackCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Even if you're not using MVVM and just using code-behind you can still bind a command to your button object and do exactly the same thing with it.  If you need make a command that has RaiseCanExecuteChanged functionality then you can use this:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute) 
                   : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, 
                   Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if( CanExecuteChanged != null )
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using Prism or MvvmLight then their own commands implement this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

this is remove all back navigation.

if (this.Frame != null)
  {
   while (this.Frame.CanGoBack) this.Frame.GoBack();
  }